# Unable to install chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb

Tags: dpkg

Morning all,

I am trying to install the ChefDK on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM, which is part of me learning Chef automation. I chose Linux because I have no skills in it, and it's probably the hardest for me to start with.
However, when trying to install chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb, I end up with the following:

```
root@ubuntuvm:~# dpkg -i chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb containing chefdk:
 chef-workstation conflicts with chefdk
  chefdk (version 3.2.30-1) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing chefdk
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chefdk_3.2.30-1_amd64.deb
```

Using "sudo apt-get install" also doesn't work, neither does it work if I use the account I created.

So I am stuck and unable to proceed. Can soemeone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: How and where did you acquire the .deb file?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy chef-workstation`. How did you get it?

Comment: ArchLinux AUR says, that `chef-workstation` and `chefdk` are [really in conflict](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chef-workstation)!

Comment: lookslike can not add answer. Just remove the other one. You can see the list in "sudo apt list", then remove "sudo apt -y purge package" packagename is of chefworkstation shown is "sudo apt list"